# How can I have Snakemake confirm remote files without using {output}

Tags: amazon-s3, snakemake

Thanks for continuing to put so much effort into Snakemake!

```
snakemake  --no-shared-fs --default-remote-provider S3 --default-remote-prefix mybucket hellos3
```

## So this does not work for me(MissingOutputException)

```
rule hellos3:
    output: "hello_s3.txt"
    shell:
        """
        echo "hello world" > hello_s3_tmp.txt
        aws s3 cp hello_s3_tmp.txt s3://mybucket/hello_s3.txt
        """
```

## But this works:

```
rule hellos3:
    output: "hello_s3.txt"
    shell:
        """
        echo "hello world" > hello_s3_tmp.txt
        cp hello_s3_tmp.txt {output}
        """
```

How can I convince Snakemake that files are appearing where they should without necessarily having Snakemake put them there? What if some remote process put them there?

Answer (score 0):

`touch` works

```
rule hellos3:
    output: "hello_s3.txt"
    shell:
        """
        echo "hello world" > hello_s3_tmp.txt
        aws s3 cp hello_s3_tmp.txt s3://mybucket/hello_s3.txt && touch {output}
        """
```